# How can I support a clothes rod on hollow drywall?

Tags: walls, hanging

I hung up two brackets with a rod. One bracket has one anchor. This has been up for quite a while, but the other day, the other bracket fell down. We tried putting it up using an anchor ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BQYFW2)) but we were having a very hard time getting the bracket in. We finally got in, but the bracket fell back down about two hours after it was put back up.

The load on the rod is clothing. It is pretty heavy. The anchor we used is a drywall anchor that can hold 75 pounds. I don't know if the wall is drywall. It seems to be a typical wall.

Is there anything we can do to hang this up in a way that it won't fall down?

Comment: Hollow-wall anchors (especially simple ones) aren't for applications where there's jostling and other dynamic forces. The drywall just can't take it. You need to put up a board between studs. Hard to offer more specific advice without seeing the situation or knowing more about what "brackets" are.

Comment: Keep in mind that the load ratings for products like that are ideals--perfect installation, flat loading, no movement. They should usually but cut by half, at least.

Comment: Drywall itself will have trouble holding that weight and movement, even with the best anchors.  Either place a 1x2 underneath the rod, nailed to studs, or use a 2x4 nailed to the studs and attach bracket to 2x4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Wall construction matters *a lot* for this project

If you don't know how your wall is built, you have to find out. To hang such a heavy item securely you must use different techniques if you have brick, concrete, plaster, wood studs, metal studs, or other material behind your wall. In an older house you may have multiple layers. You have to know.

For this answer I will assume you have hollow walls with wood studs, since that covers most residential walls in the US and Canada.  If you tell me you are in a different country or your are in a high-rise tower or this is not residential or you figure out your walls don't have wood studs, I may add another answer.

You are going to use the wood studs to support the clothes rail so it doesn't matter if you have drywall or plaster or both covering the studs.  The drywall does not support the board, the wood studs behind it do.

If you are not familiar with how a drywall-on-studs wall is built, watch some tutorials on youtube. In ten minutes you'll be enlightened.

#### Best approach: Screwed 1x6 boards do it all

A 1x6 wood board screwed to studs using #10x3" screws and cutouts for the rail.  Note the advantage of a 1x6 is it provides plenty of clearance to put a shelf on top of it without crowding the rail.  You don't need to use rail hangers.  Strength, simplicity, and convenience.

You have to find your studs and cut a piece of 1x6 long enough to span at least two studs, with your rail in between them.  Usually you'd cut the 1x6 the entire depth of the closet so it can support a shelf.

[image]

#### OK approach: Nailed 1x4 boards with rail hangers

A 1x4 board nailed to studs with 3" framing nails and rail hangers.  I don't like the nails because I don't have air tools and don't like smashing my walls with a hammer.  I'd use screws. I don't like the plastic hanger.  Get a metal one.  If you use a 1x4 and want to put a shelf on top, you have to mount the rail as low as possible and still it will be fussy to get hangers on and off.

[image]

#### Worst approach: Don't exploit wood studs

If you have studs and don't use them, it's a mistake.  If your wall is not hollow (brick, concrete) or if you have metal studs you need a different answer.  But if you have wood studs and really don't want to find them and use a board for mounting, you can do this.

I'm assuming a single or double layer of drywall.  This won't work for plaster or for drywall over plaster.

Use a 4 inch long piece of 1x4 wood and a rail hanger just like in the second picture, drill 4 holes near the corners of the wood and use 4 high quality plastic drywall anchors at each end.  So 8 anchors altogether spreading the load.  Look for other questions in these forums about how to artfully use drywall anchors in drywall.

[image]

Note in my photos, they are plaster on lath walls, many times stronger than drywall, and still two different people chose to use studs. (I didn't install these).

Comment: So you are saying to screw a wooden board into the wall, and attach the brackets to that.

Comment: In response to this comment I made substantial changes to the answer, with more background and stated assumptions.